# Method for months of the year, will not let me turn it into a hash to use for a drop_down_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is method in my Entry model

```
def self.months
  a = 1
  z = 13
  curr_year = Time.now.year
  start_month = 0
  while a < z
    month = "#{curr_year}-#{start_month +=1}-01"
    par = Date.parse(month).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    a +=1
  end
end
```

## ^ this spits out this

```
2016-01-01
2016-02-01
2016-03-01
2016-04-01
2016-05-01
2016-06-01
2016-07-01
2016-08-01
2016-09-01
2016-10-01
2016-11-01
2016-12-01
```

How can I turn this data into a hash to use for a drop down select?
I tried this(below) but I get undefined method `split' for nil:NilClas any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  h = {}
  q = Entry.months
  r = q.split(",")
  z = r.each{|a| h[a] = 0}
```

Comment: self.months returns `nil` -- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop

Comment: What are you actually trying to pass to the select?  By that I mean, what value do you want the select to have when you select say the 1st January?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def self.months
  a = 1
  z = 13
  curr_year = Time.now.year
  start_month = 0
  while a < z
    month = "#{curr_year}-#{start_month +=1}-01"
    par = Date.parse(month).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    a +=1
  end
end
```

You're not actually returning the dates you need to put them in an array and return them.

```
def self.months
  months = []
  a = 1
  z = 13
  curr_year = Time.now.year
  start_month = 0
  while a < z
    month = "#{curr_year}-#{start_month +=1}-01"
    months << Date.parse(month).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    a +=1
  end
  months
end
```

But I'd change that to

```
def self.months
  curr_year = Time.now.year
  (1..12).map do |month|
    month = "#{ curr_year }-#{ month }-01"
    Date.parse(month).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  end      
end
```

And for your select you want a 2d array.  If that's all this method is for you can do

```
def self.months
  curr_year = Time.now.year
  (1..12).map do |month|
    month = "#{ curr_year }-#{ month }-01"
    [Date.parse(month).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), my_select_value]
  end      
end
```

Substituting my_select_value for what you want the value to be for that item.

Comment: You don't have to create an intermediate date string. Just use `Date.new(curr_year, month).strftime('%F')`